# Cutting a Soft Body in Game Engine

Tags: python, game-engine, soft-body

Is it possible to cut an soft body (such as a jelly sphere) in game engine mode using a 3D cursor (as a knife)?

I'm trying to animate a jelly in the scene, that can be cut in play mode using a knife as a 3D cursor.